# I have a moving camera with known world positions, can I avoid features matching to compute fondamental matrix between two images?

Tags: matlab, opencv, matrix, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I have a monocular camera that is moving in space, I can know the pose of that camera at t and t + dt.

I have been playing with epipolar geometry on Matlab and OpenCV, from what I understood the method generally used is to compute the Fundamental matrix from inlier feature points, which leads us to the epipoles, epilines and diparity map.

In my case I know both cameras' world position, does anyone know how to express that or if it does indeed give a shortcut to an image rectification matrix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the translation of the camera from one to the other T (3x1), and the rotation R (3x3), then the essential matrix is  `E=hat(T)*R`

Look at the hat operator here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat_operator

From the essential, the fundamental is just multiplying by a form of K from both sides.

```
E=K^T * F * K
```

Where K is the intrinsic camera parameter matrix, calculated by typical calibration.